# Postgresql 14 installation issue

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, postgresql

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. Im using ubuntu 22.04 and i am trying to install postgresql.

I ve tried to troubleshoot the following error but i ve lost hours trying to do so, still not even close to resolve it:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
postgresql-14 : Depends: postgresql-common (>= 229~) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libllvm14 but it is not installable
Recommends: sysstat but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Installing PostgreSQL on Ubuntu 22.04 is generally done like this:

```
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

The default packages will install PostgreSQL 14.4.

If you have added third-party PPAs to install PostgreSQL with, this may be causing your problem. Remove them from your sources list, update `apt`, and try again.

<sup>**Note:** I install PostgreSQL on a fresh Ubuntu installation at least once a week as part of my regular database restoration testing process. The above command has always worked so long as the machine was connected to the interwebs.</sup>

Comment: well i removed everything from source list and running the above command gives me:
E: Unable to locate package postgresql
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-contrib

Comment: @Stefan Milič Did you ever run sudo apt update as indicated, before trying again?

Comment: yes, I ve did run it.

Comment: When you say you "removed everything from source list", do you mean that your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file is now empty? 